# Weird "model.summary"'s format

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, format, modelsummary

I am working on a project and when I use model.summary() to check for my model. It appears quite weird... Actually It's missing the underlines that separate layers.

Has anyone ever got this? I wonder if there is any reason for this and is it gonna affect my result :<
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFiIQ.png)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Colab for your project, it's 2.7.0 now.

Tensorflow (tf.keras) has changed the output format in model.summary

you can downgrade the tensorflow version to 2.5 in colab

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.5
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I did sth wrong...